# how can i use auth value into v-if condition in vue

Tags: laravel, vue-component

i want to use the Auth variable in vue. but its not running
my code in vue is this. This code is possible?

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="chat-message" v-if="message.user_from == '<?php echo 
Auth::user()->id; ?>'">
    <div class="chatright">
  {{message.user_from}} {{message.msg}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chatleft" v-else>
    {{message.user_from}} {{message.msg}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: so what is error given in this code?

Comment: the v-if condition didnt recognize.

Comment: i think vue didnt read auth variable

Comment: try to use {{Auth::user()->id}}

Comment: its not running too

Comment: {{Auth::user()->id}} place write static value like 1 as your user id and it work if yes then probleam is related to auth user id otherwise probleam is diffrent

Comment: i also do that but its says Raw expression

Comment: v-if="message.user_from == 1>'" test like this

Comment: i do that and its working

Comment: but when i use {{Auth::user()->id}} its says raw expression

Comment: v-if="message.user_from == <?php echo 
Auth::user()->id; ?> " write like this

Comment: i also do that sir. and still says raw expression

Comment: almost 5 hrs working with this still icant solve the problem :(

Comment: Only reputation is not matter, I up your ans  if you ask again and it ans  is true then vote up and do true , because I word many people face same problem as you and that time your activity is most important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script> var user_is = <?php echo Auth::user()->id; ?></script>
```

then put the variable in condition finally that work

Comment: <div class="chat-message" v-if="message.user_from == user_is"> i can put it like that?

Comment: do i need to declare that variable in root sir?

Comment: just up on your if condition and if that not work then decalare on root

Comment: oh god. THANK YOU SIR

Comment: its working sir. atlast thank you i appreciate ur help sir

Comment: @rookie welcome dot forget to upvote becuse other people can seen and get their solution

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation sir :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Vuex** it fits for your case or you can use the **localStorage** to persist the `userId`, otherwise you can't do this :

```
message.user_from == '<?php echo Auth::user()->id; ?>
```

Because you are trying to initialize `user_from` within the template, You should do it within the script tag

Comment: ahhh okay. im just new in vue. i didnt even know that vuex heheh ill try to understand that thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You can attach it to the root document of the HTML or you can pass the user as a prop to that Vue component.
**Note:** If you pass it in vue the HTML document object, you need to understand not to send any sensitive information of course.

In your you master page in the head section, add this:

```
<script>
    window.App = {!! json_encode(
    'user' => Auth::user(),
    'signedIn'=>Auth::check(),
]) !!};
</script>
```

And in your component, you can reach it the normal way: `App.user.something`.

Or you can pass it as a prop if you send a `$user` object.

```
<your-compoenent :user="{{$user}}"></your-component>
```

Hope this hep you.

Comment: i have this code in my master page. how this variable to be called in my vue template. i think the way i call the variable is wrong pls correct me

    <script>
      window.App = {!! json_encode([
          'user' => Auth::user()->id,
      ]) !!};
    </script>

and this is my vue template 

      <div class="chat-message" v-if="message.user_from == window.App.user">

Comment: You dont need to use the `id` attribute in the master page, but if you do it, just use it as a function. `Auth::user()->id()`. @rookie